# How can I remove windows media player 12 from windows 7 startup

Tags: windows-7, windows-media-player

I have tried everything and googled to no end.

How do I stop windows media player 12 from starting up on windows 7?

How can I remove this software from my system?

Answer (score 1):

You just remove it like most features within Windows.

[image]